# How to grant root access to a specific application from source code instead of rooting the ROM?

Tags: android, root

I'm compiling an Android ROM from source, and I have one application that I want it to be pre-installed and have it run with root permission.

How can I grant root access to this specific application, without rooting entire ROM?

Comment: Install it to system/app instead of data/app

Comment: Installing it to system/app does not grant it root access automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Hopefully you don't need root...

Typical stock Android ROMs provide root privileges to very few things, in line with the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). Instead, apps are granted the precise permissions they need.

Why exactly do you need this app to have root permissions? You should first look through the list of [all the internal unpublished Android permissions](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) to see if one of them does what you want. Since you're building a system app, you can even use `signature` permissions which are not normally available to other apps. You just need to ensure that your app is signed by the key with which you build the Android ROM - you can then distribute it with the ROM or separately, and it will still have access to the permissions you require.

The advantages of doing it this way are:

- If your app is compromised or buggy, the effects are limited.
- Your actual Java code has these permissions so there's no need to craft fiddly command lines.

So if you can possibly do your task this way, do.

## But if you really do...

If you really do need root, then things get tricky.

You have three options. In order of preference:

- Add a new system service.
- Add some alternative setuid-root binary which does just what you need.
- Modify the `su` binary to check exactly who is calling it.

If you really do need root, then I would [add a new system service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232718/how-to-add-a-system-service-to-the-android-framework). This can run as root. You would then add suitable extra APIs so that your app can call into it - and the permissions can be `signature`-level so that only your system app can call it. This is the architecturally 'correct' way to do it in Android-land.

The second or third options involve creating some command-line tool which does what you want, but I don't know a secure way for such a tool to check who is calling it. It may be acceptable to allow any app to call this functionality. If so, a new setuid-root executable might be the way to go. However, as I say, I don't know a way to stop other apps running it.

Comment: wouldn't putting the app into the system/app path make it support root anyway?

Comment: Sadly not! It means it would be granted `signatureOrSystem` permissions if it asked for them. But it's just as easy to sign the app with the system key, which will also result in the granting of those permissions - plus `signature` permissions.

Comment: so a system app cannot access other apps' data ? i guess it means that only system apps that also have root permission are really capable of doing everything.

Comment: That's right. System apps are no different from regular apps except that they are able to access APIs available via only `signatureOrSystem` permissions, plus the fact that they're signed by the ROM certificate so they can also access APIs made available by the system using `signature` capabilties. System _services_ on the other hand may well run as root - but in this sense a service is a little bit different from the sort of `Service` you can run inside an .apk.

Comment: how do you sign with a special certificate?

Comment: Thanks Adrian! It seems that there isn't a simple solution. I guess I can create a new API in the framework to do exactly what I want, but I'm trying to utilize existing code as much as possible. I'll look into the modifying su binary option, though it sounds unsafe. Thanks again!

Comment: Adrian i want to talk to you regarding the same thing asked here, i've updated my SU.C it compiled well but it is not giving root access to my app plz help.