# Is it possible to turn on/off notification from different applications programatically on android

Tags: android, notifications, system

Is it possible to turn on/off notification like "Show notifications" for programmatically?

Check this way : Settings->APps->Click on any app from a list-> Show notifications

Can I turn on/off notifications from an app programatically?

Comment: This has already been asked several times, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819249/turn-off-notifications-of-an-app-programatically-on-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667406/programmatically-disabling-enabling-notifications).
Please do a search before posting questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is posible, yes.

## But... why?

You need to [give your app root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217294/how-to-grant-root-access-to-a-specific-application-from-source-code-instead-of-r) **which is not recommended**. You will have to [learn how to modify system settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) and [update notifications status](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html)

Comment: Many reasons but here is one.. when I'm at work I'm doing App development for my employer I dont want all my Facebook, SMS and WhatsApp notifications/messages constantly popping up.  Would be great to geolocate that Im at work and apply the notification settings that I need for that environment.