# android-system: allowing an app to bind to a system service

Tags: android, android-service

This answer is to the point on how to add a system service in android:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7434249/1993710

However, i am too lazy to wait for hours each time the android makesystem builds my stuff, so i deploy my service through android-studio as a regular apk into /system/app and then inside an app that is supposed to use the service i do:

```
private ServiceConnection myAidlConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public void bindService(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("my.service","my.service.Service");
    intent.setAction("my.service.TOAST");
    intent.putExtra("text", "stulle");
    context.bindService(intent, myAidlConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

This works fine, as long as that app is also a system apk. If it's not a system apk, myAidlConnection.onServiceConnected  is just never called. I suppose that's some sort of security thing so you can't bind arbitrary system services from non-privileged apps.

Is there any way to allow my system service to be bound by anyone, or does it really have to pass the binder through getSystemService()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3rd party app can bind to any service that is "exported",regardless of whether it's a system service or not.
Is your "my.service.Service" exported?

For more information about "exported": http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported