# AOSP SystemService with TCP communication only

Tags: android, android-source, system-services

I am building a custom Android and I want to have a SystemService, which monitors some files. It needs system permissions, so that it can access files of other applications.

When searching the internet on how to build an Android SystemService, I only find examples, where some apps communicate with that service via a Manager and Binder. This is not necessary for me, as the Service should do its periodic checks and send reports via TCP/UDP. How would I build a very simple service (like a hello-world example), how would I start it automatically on boot, and how would I verify that it runs? adb shell service list?

Further, I already have a regular Android Service. Is there any easy way to integrate it as a System Service? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question: [How to add a system service to the Android Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232718/how-to-add-a-system-service-to-the-android-framework)

Basically you would need to modify `com.android.server.SystemServer` to use a newly implemented `com.android.server.SystemService` subclass of your own creation. Look at `com.android.server.twilight.TwilightService` for an example.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the TwilightService as an example!